# How to link to a random page?

Tags: php, html, random, hyperlink

I want to link to a page selected randomly from all the html files in a directory.

I have tried http://www.url.com/directory/?random but only get a 404 error.

Are there permissions that I need to change? What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no **magic** in programming.

```
http://www.example.com/directory/?random
```

Won't give you magically a random page in that directory.

You need to write a script to do that. Example **random.php**.

So you would do something like:

```
http://www.example.com/directory/random.php
```

In that **random.php** script, you need to write code for:

1. List all the pages in that directory
2. Generate a random number (1 <= n <= number_of_pages_in_directory)
3. Take the page corresponding to that number
4. Redirecting the browser to that page

Code for **random.php** should be relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  function selectRandomhtml(){ // code to select and return filename string}
?>

<a href="http://www.url.com/directory/<?php selectRandomhtml() ?>">random</a>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You cant try something like that:

```
if (isset($_GET['random'])){
 $folder = './prova/';
    if ($handle = opendir($folder)) {    
    $arr = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !is_dir($folder.$file))
         array_push($arr,$file);
    }  
    //echo the page...
    echo file_get_contents($folder.$arr[rand(0,count($arr)-1)]);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an overview of all possible pages. You can in some way create an array of all the possible options, and then on a visit to ex. url.com/?random have the server (or the client) route the user to one of these random pages.

There is no automataticality at all present that should route you to a random page by adding ?random at the end of the URL...